Has the White House put out any statement about Biden dropping out?
I'm making a distinction here between the White House (WH) and Joe Biden himself. The WH, as an institution, may or may not be concerned with whom the next candidate is. I see in the realm of the possible that the WH may be punting on commenting on this matter when they can defer to Biden--the (now former) candidate--on all questions on this issue.
So, has the White House put out any statement about Biden dropping out?
(N.B. Biden himself did post a letter on social media. It does not e.g. have any WH letterhead or similar WH stationery. He also tweeted that from his "Joe Biden" account rather than the official POTUS one--his profile makes that distinction--"Official account is @POTUS.")
FWTW, the GOP has been pouncing on this angle:

In the wake of Mr Biden's decision, [Trump] declared the president "was not fit to run... and is certainly not fit to serve". Other senior Republicans joined him in their criticism, and called on Mr Biden to leave the White House immediately, not just the Democratic candidacy.

So, while the WH would perhaps prefer not to comment, they might not be able to avoid all Qs on the matter, e.g. in a presser. I guess we'll see in the upcoming days...

Why don't you wait a few days? Or read the newspapers and the White House website? It's hard to see what's the point of asking this question at the time you did: any answer will be almost immediately out-of-date, and the purpose of SE is to build a repository of useful answers to questions, not just to debate current affairs as they happen.

@timetakesitstoll What is FWTW supposed to stand for?

@Kyralessa: "for what's it worth". Speaker Johnson has joined that chorus https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gEhU46HSbt0 Whether the Republican majority in the House will move to impeach Biden in the remaining time, I'm not sure, but I guess they don't find it worth the hassle at this point.

"For what it's worth" abbreviates to FWIW, not FWTW.

@Kyralessa: "for what's that worth".

Hmmmm, OK, well, "for what's that worth" isn't good English (it should be "for what that's worth"), and FWTW is a decidedly uncommon acronym:  https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&q=FWIW,FWTW&hl=en-US  So you can do as you like, but if you use FWTW instead of FWIW, fewer people will understand what you mean.

@Kyralessa: I guess using the abbreviations saves me from having to correct my spelling more often...

Sure thing, no objection to the abbreviations as such.  But I'd recommend FWIW over FWTW.

@Kyralessa: FWIW sometimes stands for "from what I know".

"Know" doesn't start with a W, though.  "From what I know" would be "FWIK".  More commonly seen is AFAIK: "As far as I know."

On July 22 2024, the White House published Remarks by President Biden and Vice President Harris at a Campaign Event
In these remarks, Biden acknowledges that he dropped out of the race and asks his supporters to rally behind Harris. One example:

Look, so I’m hoping you’ll give every bit of your heart and soul that you gave to me to Kamala.  And — and I want you to know: I won’t be on the ticket, but I’m still going to be fully, fully engaged.  I’ve got six months left of my presidency, and I’m determined to get as much done as I possibly can, both foreign policy and domestic policy; keep lowering costs for families; continue to speak out on guns and childcare, eldercare, prescription drugs, and climate.

Considering that no other statement has been released by now, I think this (and other speeches in future) may be the closest we can get.

Biden also gave a speech from the Oval Office now, on the matter https://youtu.be/DjC2fBEU2CQ?t=1872

BTW, it seems that in neither of these communications did Biden respond in any way to GOP calls for him to immediately resign the presidency. I guess they prefer not to answer that, for the time being, at least.

The White House staff, like all Federal employees except the President himself and the Vice President, are subject to the Hatch Act.  There are strict, and complex, rules about what they are allowed to publicly say regarding elections.
In a novel and evolving situation like this one, especially given that the White House has, in fact, little to actually say, it isn’t surprising that they are keeping quiet.

As of the writing of this answer, the White House has not issued a statement about President Biden dropping out from candidacy for the upcoming presidential election.
